# timezone conversion in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm probably missing something about timezones:

```
>>> import datetime, pytz
>>> date = datetime.datetime(2013,9,3,16,0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
>>> date.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 15, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I was expecting

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 15, 00, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Can anyone explain me where these 51 minutes come from?

Thanks,

Jean-Philippe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UTC offset gives (`date.tzinfo.utcoffset(date)`):

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 540)
```

This is 540 seconds or 9 minutes.

In France the switch to UTC was made on March 11, 1911 and the clocks were turned back 9 minutes and 21 seconds ([source 1](http://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/europe), [source 2](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/default/src/NodaTime.Test/TimeZones/ParisTest.cs)):

> Until 1911, Paris was 9 minutes and 21 seconds off UTC.

You can also see it here ([Paris time in 1911](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=195&year=1911)) where the time goes from March 11, 12:01:00 AM to March 10, 11:51:39 PM.

Comment: that seems very weird.. totally unexpected

Comment: OK. It looks like I completely misunderstand what UTC really is !

Comment: Well, Wikipedia define Central European Time as " 1 hour ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The time offset from UTC can be written as +01:00". I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 7):

Read the note at the very begining of [`pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) ; use `.localize()` method to create timezone-aware datetime object:

```
import datetime
import pytz

naive_dt = datetime.datetime(2013,9,3,16,0)
dt = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris").localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)

to_s = lambda d: d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z')
print(to_s(dt))
print(to_s(dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)))
```

#### Output

```
2013-09-03 16:00:00 CEST+0200
2013-09-03 14:00:00 UTC+0000
```

I don't know why you are expecting `15:00 UTC` here.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Simeon for your answer. It made me realize how shallow is my understanding of all of this. The following experimentations lost me a little more...

```
>>> import datetime, pytz
>>> date_paris = datetime.datetime(2013,9,3,16,0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
>>> date_utc = datetime.datetime(2013,9,3,16,0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
>>> date_paris.astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 15, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> date_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 18, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Why this 9 minutes offset shows up when converting in one direction but not the other? The following piece of code concentrate all disappointment:

```
>>> date_paris
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 16, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' PMT+0:09:00 STD>)
>>> date_paris.astimezone(pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 17, 51, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```